# how to reduce size of dojo resource bundle in my project

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo for dojo gauges.I need to place all files of dojo in my project. It is occupying lot of memory in my project. I need to place dijit, dojox, dojo folders in my project. In dojo gauges when i am deleting unnecessary files of dojo resources my application is not working. I was searched in google iam not found anything. How can i reduce the dojo resources size? please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dojo web builder](http://build.dojotoolkit.org/), just select the modules you need/want and click on the **Build** button. This web builder will return a single file that contains all modules you need (the once you selected + the ones that are required to make these work). Then you can pick the version you want (uncompressed or minified) and you're done.

If you don't see the left side (I'm having issues right now when I open it using the latest Google Chrome), try a different browser.